# Programmatically adding Buttons to Relative Layout

Tags: android

I know this probably isn't the best type of question to be asking here due to lack of research, but I actually have no idea where to start looking here. Everything seems like it should work just fine. Anyway, I'm trying to add several buttons to my app UI programmatically as to insure the UI fits and adapts to all screens seamlessly. [Here is a very rough idea of the format I'm needing (with text in each button of course)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MN7DH.png)

[And this is what I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yauGt.png)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    Point size = new Point();
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getRealSize(size);
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size.x / 5, 200);
    padding = size.x / 5;
    addButtons();
}

public void addButtons() {
    Button update = new Button(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams updateParams = params;
    updateParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    update.setLayoutParams(updateParams);
    update.setPadding(padding, 0, 0, 0);
    update.setText("Update Me!");
    update.setOnClickListener(new ClickHandler("app_update"));
    updateId = update.generateViewId();
    update.setId(updateId);
    layout.addView(update);

    Button install = new Button(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams installParams = params;
    installParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, update.getId());
    installParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    install.setLayoutParams(installParams);
    install.setPadding(padding, 0, 0, 0);
    install.setText("Install LastBox");
    install.setOnClickListener(new ClickHandler("kodi_install"));
    installId = install.generateViewId();
    install.setId(installId);
    layout.addView(install);

    Button dlFamily = new Button(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams dlFamilyParams = params;
    dlFamilyParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, install.getId());
    dlFamilyParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, install.getId());
    dlFamily.setLayoutParams(dlFamilyParams);
    dlFamily.setPadding(padding, 0, 0, padding);
    dlFamily.setText("Download Family Build");
    dlFamily.setOnClickListener(new ClickHandler("family_download"));
    dlFamilyId = dlFamily.generateViewId();
    dlFamily.setId(dlFamilyId);
    layout.addView(dlFamily);

    Button upFamily = new Button(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams upFamilyParams = params;
    upFamilyParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, install.getId());
    upFamilyParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, install.getId());
    upFamily.setLayoutParams(upFamilyParams);
    upFamily.setPadding(padding, padding, 0, 0);
    upFamily.setText("Update Family Build");
    upFamily.setOnClickListener(new ClickHandler("family_update"));
    upFamilyId = upFamily.generateViewId();
    upFamily.setId(upFamilyId);
    layout.addView(upFamily);

    Button dlAdult = new Button(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams dlAdultParams = params;
    dlAdultParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, dlFamily.getId());
    dlAdultParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, install.getId());
    dlAdult.setLayoutParams(dlAdultParams);
    dlAdult.setPadding(padding, 0, 0, padding);
    dlAdult.setText("Download Adult Build");
    dlAdult.setOnClickListener(new ClickHandler("adult_download"));
    dlAdultId = dlAdult.generateViewId();
    dlAdult.setId(dlAdultId);
    layout.addView(dlAdult);

    Button upAdult = new Button(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams upAdultParams = params;
    upAdultParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, upFamily.getId());
    upAdultParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, install.getId());
    upAdult.setLayoutParams(upAdultParams);
    upAdult.setPadding(padding, padding, 0, 0);
    upAdult.setText("Update Adult Build");
    upAdult.setOnClickListener(new ClickHandler("adult_update"));
    upAdultId = upAdult.generateViewId();
    upAdult.setId(upAdultId);
    layout.addView(upAdult);
}
```

I'm not even looking for some magical "fix it for me because I'm too lazy" solution. Point me in the right direction, show me where I need to look, stuff like that. I enjoy solving these problems but starting in the right spot would be marvelous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params` for all of your buttons. In Java all non primitive types assignments are made by reference, so when you do

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams updateParams = params;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams installParams = params;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams dlFamilyParams = params;
```

and so on, you are assigning the same object in memory to various variables. Variables are only textual references to certain memory addresses, so with different names you are referencing always to the same object in memory.

You set for each button some different layout params properties to position them into the view. But if we told we are referencing always to the same object in memory, then we are updating always the same object and so we are overriding previous settings and we are keeping only last settings.

Thus you are setting the same params object to all your buttons.

The combination of these errors results in having all your buttons with the same RelativeLayout.LayoutParams with his settings, they are placed one over the other and you can see only the last added.

You have to create a different params object for each button like follows:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams updateParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size.x / 5, 200);
...
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams installParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size.x / 5, 200);
...
```

To analyze views problems I suggest you to use Layout Inspector tool, accessible by menu Tools -> Android

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This did the trick. I'm most familiar with C++ so it was odd for me to discover that most variable in Java are reference! Fascinating. Anyway, the buttons do not have text in them, despite my setText methods on each button. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RelativeLayout layout =   (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );


for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
     Button button= new Button(this);
     button.setText("some_text");
     button.setId(i);

    // lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, <Id>);

     layout.addView(tv2, lp); 
}
```